# How to use Python charrnn implementation on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, terminal, lstm

**Hello there,**

I want to use Andrej Karpathy's [Character-Based LSTM](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) (char-rnn) to generate text, but neither have a Linux OS nor Torch installed, so I want to use the Python implemetation of it which uses Tensorflow and can be installed via pip (view package details on PyPI [here](https://pypi.org/project/charrnn/)).

This package installs a command line application `charrnn` and I can't quite figure out how to use it.
For instance, this is what I tried to set the directory of my dataset:

```
charrnn --datasets directory C:/Users/nemes/Documents/Projekt_MIDICSV/input
```

I get the following error:

```
usage: charrnn [-h] [--version] [--verbose] [--model file] [--window length]
               [--batch size] [--datasets directory]
               {train,decode} ...
charrnn: error: invalid choice: 'C:/Users/nemes/Documents/Projekt_MIDICSV/input' (choose from 'train', 'decode')
```

I tried many different variations with and without 'train', but never succeeded. The documentation says the default path is 'datasets' - where is this path?

I used only train as well:

```
charrnn train

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nemes\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\nemes\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\nemes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\charrnn.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nemes\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\charrnn\__main__.py", line 27, in main
    run(args)
  File "c:\users\nemes\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\charrnn\train.py", line 165, in run
    t_train, t_val = train_val_split(get_text(args.datasets), args)
  File "c:\users\nemes\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\charrnn\text.py", line 26, in get_text
    for dataset in os.listdir(directory):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] System can't find the following path: 'datasets'
```

If somebody is familiar with this kind of library: Can you explain how to make through the training process, from setting the directory to setting the batch size and number of deep layers to output the generated text?

*Thanks for yout help!*

Comment: You didn't remove the placeholder "directory" from your call. Did you try: `charrnn --datasets C:/Users/nemes/Documents/Projekt_MIDICSV/input train` ?

Comment: @Matthias Still doesn't work. It says:

Comment: (too long to comment, see post below)